# how to update diagram after change in Chart in visual paradigm 10?

Tags: visual-paradigm

I am trying to draw process of my company in visual paradigm 10.
at first, I draw a chart of organization and then refer to the chart I created all the diagrams. now  I want to change the chart of our organization, for example, the name of some unit. I want to update all lane based on these changes. how can I update all process diagram ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make the change using Find and Replace dialog (Ctrl + F). In the Find and Replace dialog you can limit the scope to only work on the Organization Unit and BP Pools/Lanes to avoid making unintended changes to other model elements.